# How can I reach the value of list item with iterator?

Tags: c++, list

I have a list;

```
list<Car*>* carList = new list<Car*>;
```

But when I try to reach element's property app stops running.

```
list<Car*>::iterator i = CarList->end();
while(i!=carList->begin())
{
   string plate = (*i)->Plate;//Here app stops
   i--;
}
```

Comment: I doubt you can even compile your code.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed aracList to carList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how iterators work.  You iterate from begin to end or rbegin to rend.  Your code will at best cause an infinite loop, and most likely cause a segfault.  Also, do you need to be storing pointers?  You could probably be storing copies.

```
std::list<Car> cars;
//insert a few cars

for (std::list<Car>::iterator it = cars.begin(), end = cars.end(); it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << it->plate << std::endl;
}
```

The code is almost the exact same for reverse iteration:

```
for (std::list<Car>::reverse_iterator it = cars.rbegin(), end = cars.rend(); it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << it->plate << std::endl;
}
```

---

Working with pointers instead complicates it a bit, but not too badly:

```
std::list<Car*>* cars = new std::list<Car*>;
//insert a few Car*

for (std::list<Car*>::iterator it = cars->begin(), end = cars->end(); it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << (*it)->plate << std::endl;
}
```

Without seeing a broader context though, my guess is that you're unnecessarily using dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate from `rbegin` to `rend`.

If you still want to use `begin` and `end`, you can do the following:

```
list<Car*>::iterator i = CarList->end();
while(i!=AracList->begin())
{
   i--;
   string plate = (*i)->Plate;//Here app stops
}
```

Actually, `end` points to one position **after** the actual end of your list, this is why you can't deallocate `end()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate from end to begin use reversed iterators:

```
list<Car*>::reverse_iterator i = CarList->rbegin();
list<Car*>::reverse_iterator end = CarList->rend();
while(i!=end)
{
   string plate = (*i)->Plate;//Here app stops
   ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't even compile at below line:

```
list<Car*> carList = new list<Car*>;
           ^^^ carList is not a pointer, you can't new it
```

Suggest you store Car objects in List

```
List<Car> cars;
Car car1;
cars.push_back(car1);
for (auto it = cars.begin(), end = cars.end(); it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << it->plate << std::endl;
}
```

If you store Car pointer in List(You may need to store pointer for polymorphism reason, class derived from Car can also be stored in the list) but I suggest you store shared pointer in std::list.

```
C++11
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Car*>> Cars;

C++03:
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Car*> > Cars;
                               ^^ you need a space to differentiate from operator >>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the container `end` functions returns *one beyond* the actual end. That's why your program crashes. Either use the `rbegin`/`rend` functions as proposed by the other answers, or put `i--` *before* accessing the iterator.